# Add a Contains("string") functionality Azure Table LINQpad query?

Tags: linq, linqpad

OK, this doesn't work due to Azure Table query subset constraints:

```
var res = tcmarketnlog.Where(t => t.Level == level && t.Message.Contains("151207151510") && t.Timestamp >= start && t.Timestamp <= end).Take(1000);
```

The t.Message.Contains("151207151510") bombs. However, there must be some way to then search the results in LINQpad and select only the results with this string in the message.

For example, I could not coerce the result into a variable that was then queriable again with LINQ. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use `string.Contains` on an Azure Table Queryable, you can still turn it into an Enumerable and then apply the additional filter to only show the results you want.  However, it means that it will return all records that meet the other criteria over the network before then limiting them on the client side to only those rows where the Message field contains the specified string.

`var res = tcmarketnlog.Where(t => t.Level == level && t.Timestamp >= start && t.Timestamp <= end).AsEnumerable().Where(t => t.Message.Contains("151207151510")).Take(1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe message is null. Just check message null before contains. pls try this:

```
        var res = tcmarketnlog.Where(t => t.Level == level 
                                     && t.Message != null && t.Message.Contains("151207151510") 
                                     && t.Timestamp >= start && t.Timestamp <= end).Take(1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is never null in our case.